# How to run a file in variable

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I want to run this command:
`` ././pscan `cat ips` 22 ``
but the script don't run corectly

```
ips file:
1.1
2.2
3.3
4.4
5.5
```

and i want to run command e.g:
`././pscan 1.1 22
././pscan 2.2 22
././pscan 3.3 22
././pscan 4.4 22
././pscan 5.5 22`

the script `pscan` works perfectly when i type on single command `././pscan 1.1 22`

and i want to run more than 5.5 e.g 100.241 etc..

Comment: PLS only tag the relevant languages. This has nothing to do with Python

Comment: oh okey,,, i'm so sorry

Comment: What you want to achieve with the first `./` you know what it means? You have an special reason to use in that way?

Comment: yes i know what is means, but i want the answer of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to run your command with each line/word of your input? You can use a loop and `read` to achieve that:

```sh
while read line; do
  ./script.sh "$line" other args
done < input_file
```

or with `xargs`:

```sh
< input_file xargs -L1 -I{} ./script {} other args
```

Pay attention to how whitespace is (not) handled.

Comment: i will try now !

Comment: ```while read line; do
  ./script.sh "$line" other args
done < input_file```        This works Thanks!